# Как преобразовать нечитаемые кириллические символы после выборки из MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка

Использую PDO:

```
$dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$serverName;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8",$username,
$password,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
$dbh->query($sql);
```

выводятся кириллические символы в виде вопросов:

```
[IDStore] => �_106
[0] => �_106
```

Попытка преобразовать кириллицу путем

```
mb_convert_encoding($text, 'utf-8', mb_detect_encoding($text));
```

также не приводит к желаемому:

```
[0] => ?_104
[1] => ?_117
[2] => ?_14D
[3] => ?_16
```

Как правильно преобразовать?

Comment: А кодировка поля точно utf8, а не utf8mb4?

Comment: 1) на сервере должна быть кодировка у таблиц и полей `utf8_general_ci` 2) При коннекте к БД кодировка должна быть `utf-8` 3) `Html` так же должна быть в `utf-8`

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась так:

```
mb_convert_encoding($row["IDStore"], 'utf-8', 'cp-1251');
```